# meaning of 'hashiri ni hashirimashita'?

Tags: meaning

What is a good translation of 'hashiri ni hashirimashita'?

I'm familiar with the general masu-stem-ni-iku construction: kai ni iku, "go in order to shop" - but this sounds like "run in order to run", which sounds strange.

This is from "stories you can read in 10 minutes - first grade".  A hare and hedgehog are racing, and the hedgehog keeps tricking the hare, and the hare wants to race over and over.

A Japanese friend said it is something like "to run over and over", but that I could not make my own constructions i.e. "mi ni miru", so I am missing something.

(btw I don't have kanji - it's a first grade book - mostly kana).

Comment: How about "I ran and ran"? 見に見る is not used, but its reason is also covered in the linked question.